# What is the 'lang:en-US' for in 'Share to LinkedIn button' JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right"></script>
```

Here is the code I got from http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator

What is the `lang: en_US` for? I've never seen this kind of usage of JavaScript (or quote of .js link) before.

Comment: I'm guessing the LinkedIn script reads the contents of the script tag to see if there are any parameters, and in this case there is one set for the language of the share widget.

Answer (score 3):

`lang: fr_FR` is use for the Specify language for label of your share button.

From the [API Reference](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/tags-and-templates)

The contents inside of the script tag are made available as a template (see "Templating").

**Templating**
Tags that allow for templating use a special JS syntax for creating HTML within the script tag's contents. This lightweight templating makes it easy to quickly display results.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am still puzzled how the `in.js` read the content. Just use `script.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like a JavaScript `label` statement, which as you pointed out isn't very common, and it is used so you can identify a specific loop and then use a statement referring to that loop (though normally `break` or `continue`). There's good write up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) here explaining it much more thoroughly. Specifically here it is obviously used to identify the language but without looking closely at the code I'm not sure how it is implemented.